# "Cut back/down my shifts" or "cut back/down on my shifts"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

I'm confused because I see the two versions on Google Books:

"[cut back/down my shifts](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22cut%20down%20my%20shifts%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiapvK1p-_dAhXFf7wKHXdnBbYQ_AUIEygA&biw=1856&bih=960)"

"[cut back/down on my shifts](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1856&bih=960&tbm=bks&ei=4lm3W_XsC4SJ8wXOlrWoBg&q=%22cut%20down%20on%20my%20shifts%22&oq=%22cut%20down%20on%20my%20shifts%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...164925.165090.0.165214.3.3.0.0.0.0.107.225.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.106...33i10k1.0.uNl8Dli9TMc)"

What's the correct alternative? Or they are both correct?

Comment: If you are finding both versions in books, why would you think one is right and one is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to cut back on the number of hours one works in a shift, or per week, etc.
- cut back down on the number of hours one works

**The boss cut back my hours**. Now, I only have 20 hours a week instead of 25.

You would **only say "cut back down"** **if **previously** the hours had been cut back**.

**cut down** my shifts** is not idiomatic.

The board was cut down to fit the opening.  [reduced in size]

For shifts: to cut back my hours, no **on**.

cut back on [something] means to consume less of something

Answer (score 0):

In my view, neither one of them [cut down, cut down on] is "correct" there but you will hear *some* native speakers saying both.

To **cut down *on*** something is to consume less of it, or to engage in it less frequently.

> He wanted to cut down on carbohydrates.
>
> You should really cut down on your drinking.
>
> He made a resolution to cut down on playing video games.

Some native speakers would "repurpose" the phrase to mean "to lower the number or frequency of something"

> I wish I could cut down on my shifts at the fast-food restaurant.
>
> I wish I could cut down my shifts at the fast-food restaurant.

P.S. As for **cut back (on)** it means "to reduce the amount of something".

> The soup's good but you might want to cut back on the hot peppers.
>
> The company is cutting back on its advertising budget.

If the speaker works in an industry where the number  of shifts per week can vary, and the duration of these shifts can vary as well, both phrases could work, since the speaker could have the total hours in mind in either case. In these industries workers "take shifts":

> Can you take the 4PM to 11PM shift on Wednesday and the breakfast shift on Thursday?

Comment: There are a lot of writers using "cut back on her shifts" https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22cut+back+on+her+shifts%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbs8eJqu_dAhUShrwKHfeDBo8Q_AUIEygB&biw=1856&bih=960

Comment: Yes, but you added **cut back** after I'd answered your question in its first form, which did not mention "cut back".  **cut back** and **cut down** are not identical.